# Gradle 3.0 No resource found from other module in project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0, gradle-3.0

I have upgraded Android Gradle plugin to 3.0. I have multiple modules in my project. So for different buildTypes (say, *release*) in module, I have also added `releaseImplementation project(':otherModule')` in main App module gradle.
In some layout xml file in main App module, when I am trying to get some resource **(present in `otherModule`)**, I get following error.

**AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/some_string').**

My project Structure looks like

```
.
├── app-module
│   |__ build.gradle
│   |__ src
│       |__ main
│            |__ res
├── othermodule
│   |__ src
│   |    |__ main
│   |         |__ res
│   |__ build.gradle
|
|__ build.gradle (root)
|__ settings.gradle
```

Comment: may be your module not imported correctly Right  Click on App >Open Modular Setting >Dependencies and add their n give a try

Comment: Checked...library imported as `:otherModule` in Module Settings>Dependencies.